# mysql JSON_EXTRACT - don't return any results

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli, extract

I create a simple search form. Firstly I explode words and make some query (for search multiple words at once). Also, I want to search only in Movie titles. Movie titles can be found in movie_data.

My database called movies have rows: 
**id** and
**movie_data** - contains movie data in JSON. Example storaged data in json:

```
{"movie_title":"Forrest Gump","movie_cover":"http://1.fwcdn.pl/po/09/98/998/7314731.6.jpg","movie_name_en":"","movie_desc":"Historia życia Forresta, chłopca o niskim ilorazie inteligencji z niedowładem kończyn, który staje się miliarderem i bohaterem wojny w Wietnamie.","movie_year":"1994","movie_genres":"DramatKomedia"}
```

Here is my code. This code don't return any results.

```
$query = 'Forrest Gump';
$words = explode(' ', $query);

$i = 0;
$len = count($words);
$query_build = '';
foreach ($words as $item) {
    if ($i == $len - 1) {
       $query_build .= ' titlemov LIKE "%$item%"';
    } else {
       $query_build .= ' titlemov LIKE "%$item%" OR ';
    }
    // …
    $i++;
}


$sql = "SELECT movie_data, JSON_EXTRACT(movie_data, '$.movie_title') AS titlemov 
FROM movies WHERE $query_build";
```

This code don't result any items

UPDATE
I updated my code.

```
$query = 'Forrest Gump';
$words = explode(' ', $query);

$i = 0;
$len = count($words);
$query_build = '';
foreach ($words as $item) {
    if ($i == $len - 1) {
       $query_build .= " JSON_EXTRACT(movie_data, \'$.movie_title\') LIKE '%$item%'";
    } else {
       $query_build .= " JSON_EXTRACT(movie_data, \'$.movie_title\') LIKE '%$item%' OR ";
    }
    // …
    $i++;
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE $query_build";
```

Now i getting error:

```
Warning: mysqli::query(): (22032/3141): Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_extract: "Missing a comma or '}' after an object member." at position 228. in /search.php on line 43
```

Line 43:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

var_dump of $sql var:

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(movie_data, '$.movie_title') LIKE '%Forrest%' OR JSON_EXTRACT(movie_data, '$.movie_title') LIKE '%Gump%'
```

Hmm?

Comment: Your variable $item is in single quotes, PHP does not evaluate variables within single quotes.

Comment: Cool story bro. Was there a question?  What is the contents of `$sql` before you send it to the database?  And what's up with `$.movie_title` , what are we expecting that to evaluate to? Also, PHP string literals enclosed in single quotes aren't evaluated....appending to `$query_build` is tacking on a string contains a *literal* `$item`

Comment: $.var is the mysql syntax for extracting the key "var" from a JSON string.

Comment: @Devon: if we want to pass a dollar sign character to MySQL, we need to take care that PHP doesn't try to do an evaluation on it.  I was asking OP a question to help identify where a problem might be. But echo/var_dump of `$sql` *before* it;s sent to the database would be a way for OP to narrow down where the problem is...  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @spencer7593, as I pointed out on Ray's answer, PHP does not evaluate `$.`

Comment: @Devon: which we would find out if we *observed* the contents of `$sql`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`titlemov` doesn't exist for your where clause to use.  What you want to use inside your where clause (specified in the `$query_build`) is the `JSON_SEARCH` function.  Here's what it looks like in general with wildcards for the movie name:

```
SELECT movie_data, movie_data->'$.movie_title' AS titlemov FROM movies 
 WHERE  JSON_SEARCH(movie_data->'$.movie_title', 'one', "%orrest Gum%") IS NOT NULL;
```

You'll just need to modify your `$query_build` string.  I also drop the needless `JSON_EXTRACT` function calls.

Try this:

```
$query_build = " JSON_SEARCH(movie_data->'$.movie_title', 'one', '%$item%') IS NOT NULL";
```

Final note, I'm assuming `$item` is not a user supplied string, otherwise this opens you up to SQL injection.  If it is supplied by user, you'll want to use a prepared statement and bind this value.

Comment: PHP actually doesn't evaluate `$.`, atleast not in newer versions.  This  may be why MySQL choose that specific syntax.

Comment: Thank you for a reply. I updated my code. But still i don't get any results.

Comment: @PatrykPatryk Sorry, meant to tell you to use json search... see my update.

Comment: @Devon you're correct, the `$.` does not evaluate, my bad, updating my answer.